# Unable to load Highcharts in Android Web VIew

Tags: android, webview, highcharts

I am using highcharts for my web application to be displayed for specific purpose it works fine with web app and loads perfectly. But when i load the same web page into my android web view the highcharts won't load and shows errors in the highcharts.js files. Can anyone let me know what can be the issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the error.

Comment: Did you check that ? http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#UsingJavaScript

Comment: @LaurentMeyer yeah i have checked that ...i have already enabled the javascript

Comment: Ok, then can you post your error like @Ondkloss said?

Comment: You could also post your JS and your code in order that we can reproduce the error...

Comment: i dont know how but when i tried to run it today again it has started to display it. Thanks for the help @LaurentMeyer